# Hex encode ECDSA keys in node.js

Tags: node.js, openssl, public-key-encryption, ecdsa

I'm building a nodejs app that talks to an API server. The API server requires that each request I make to it includes a `X-Signature` header using the `prime256v1` ECDSA curve and `sha256` hash on a particular set of data.

I looked through the [crypto](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) and [tls](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html) documentation but didn't find anything suitable. I have successfully generated a private key with `openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey` but it is in PEM format. I have also generated a DER format key. Both of these include some extra metadata like the curve used and in the case of PEM, comments.

I can use these keys for signing operations on my side, but the server requires that I upload a public key using hex encoding (so the server can verify the signatures I make on my requests.)

Specifically the server wants something like the output of the following Python code:

```
from ecdsa import SigningKey
from binascii import hexlify
hexlify(SigningKey.from_pem(content).to_string())
```

Sample output for a pubkey (no newlines): `c5bd76cd0cd948de17a31261567d219576e992d9066fe1a6bca97496dec634e2c8e06f8949773b300b9f73fabbbc7710d5d6691e96bcf3c9145e15daf6fe07b9`

I would prefer not adding python as a dependency to my node app... anyone know of a way I can extract the binary data representing my private key from the PEM or DER files, so I can put it in a buffer and call `buffer.toString('hex')`? Or a way I can use the native `crypto` library to generate the ECDSA keypair? Or a library that would do the same?

Answer (score 0):

openssl itself can print out the guts of things, in hex.

Doe the key change? sounds like you can just decode into hex one time, and use that?  No need for dependencies - just paste the hex into your node source?